# Unable to run telescope / meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

Im trying to follow the instructions from http://www.telesc.pe/docs/installing-telescope/
Managed to install node.js and npm using the link on the page. I have also installed meteor and meteorite. I have also pulled the latest update using `git clone git@github.com:TelescopeJS/Telescope.git`

I can can run another meteor app. (like a demo 'myapp')

But when I try and launch meteor from inside the 'telescope' folder, I get the following:

```
*Last login: Fri Aug  1 19:52:52 on ttys000
static-239:~ shwaytaj$ cd telescope
static-239:telescope shwaytaj$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/telescope ]]]]]
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     

iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'readable-stream' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/shwaytaj/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/node" "/Users/shwaytaj/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/npm" "install" "connect@2.9.0"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/shwaytaj/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/05415a8891ea87a00fb1e2388585f2ca5a38e0da/.npm/package-new-1efnvtc
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shwaytaj/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/05415a8891ea87a00fb1e2388585f2ca5a38e0da/.npm/package-new-1efnvtc/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
mailchimp: updating npm dependencies -- mailchimp...
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/request/2.39.0'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/request/2.39.0']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/request/2.39.0',
npm ERR!   parent: 'mailchimp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/shwaytaj/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/node" "/Users/shwaytaj/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/npm" "install" "mailchimp@1.0.3"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/shwaytaj/telescope/packages/mailchimp/.npm/package-new-55uyws
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /Users/shwaytaj/.npm/request/2.39.0
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/request/2.39.0'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shwaytaj/telescope/packages/mailchimp/.npm/package-new-55uyws/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
fast-render: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'readable-stream' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/shwaytaj/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/node" "/Users/shwaytaj/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/npm" "install" "connect@2.13.0"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/shwaytaj/.meteorite/packages/fast-render/arunoda/meteor-fast-render/149984b1aff3a5642a270aff9bd9006872c8302e/.npm/package-new-1c6pww9
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/shwaytaj/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shwaytaj/.meteorite/packages/fast-render/arunoda/meteor-fast-render/149984b1aff3a5642a270aff9bd9006872c8302e/.npm/package-new-1c6pww9/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
=> Errors prevented startup:
While building package `iron-router`:
error: couldn't install npm package
While building package `mailchimp`:
error: couldn't install npm package
While building package `fast-render`:
error: couldn't install npm package
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.*
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you were using `sudo` too much. Make sure that you're the owner of all files within `~/.npm` and `~/.meteorite`, so basically

```
sudo chown -R username:username ~/.npm ~/.meteorite
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting this because you did:

> sudo npm install -g meteorite

If you do sudo mrt in the teloscope app folder it will probably run fine.

If you want to resolve the issue you will need to fix your permissions, you can do:

> sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm

See here for more:
https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/